# open a text file such as xml or markdown as plain text without interpreting the formatinstruction in MS-Word

Tags: microsoft-word, xml, file-format, text-formatting

Is there a **key combination** or 'open as...' plain text **menu option** that can be used?

Subsidiary double question: will it also work with anz file (with random byte contatint)  AND what are the drawbacks then?

The idea is e.g. to save a word document as xml, to edit it as pure xml in word itself again to correct a style definition in plain text, to save it and to reopen it again as usual now as corrected word document.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your word document is saved in a new office format (.docx extension) you can rename extension from .docx to .zip (it is useful to have option show file extension for known file types ticked in folder view menu).
Now you can either extract that zip file or navigate directly inside it to see folders and files (depends on your OS or File manager). xml files are visible inside.
I strongly suggest to use some other editor for xml, e.g. Notepad++
After you are done with xml edits, change back extension to how it was before, to .docx (if you extracted the zip before, pack it back to zip again).